# Why does my C code crash?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, random

I'm trying out the syntax in C, as it's new to me. I was just starting with arrays, loops and random numbers, so I wrote this really simple test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arr[9];

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand();
        printf("%d \n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

I compile it with gcc and run from command prompt. Runs fine, prints each element in the array... And then crashes. Why? Is there something with the code logic?

Thank you in advance! This is my first question here, so I apologize in advance if I made any mistakes in question asking rules.

Comment: `i < 10` ---> `i < 9`

Comment: The array is of `9` elements. You are accessing `10`.

Comment: Accessing array out of bound make program behave erroneous (invokes undefined behavior). Program crash is one of them.

Comment: Thank you! Silly mistake on my part. I thought something like this would be pointed out by the compiler...

Comment: @JR General rule in C: If you're very, very lucky, the compiler will catch your mistakes. If you're merely lucky, your mistakes will crash the program. But if you're not lucky, your mistakes will silently corrupt data elsewhere or lead to unpredictable behavior later on in the program.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I fixed that problem, but I still get a crash if I use multi-dimensional arrays with higher numbers. For example this: [https://pastebin.com/5CGSAFgL](https://pastebin.com/5CGSAFgL) What is wrong here?

Comment: This was a well presented question.

Comment: Also, I'm afraid that you won't win the 'Original Title of the Month' award:(

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing memory beyond the limits of the array, which you don't have permission to, which results in undefined behavior. You do that because you have an array of 9 elements, but you attempt to access 10. To rectify, you should write:

```
// ...
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that, but it still crashes if I use higher numbers. For example, this crashes too: [https://pastebin.com/GYUKnQW2](https://pastebin.com/GYUKnQW2)

Comment: @JR It's one question per question site.

Comment: @EugeneSh. oh, I see. Thank you. I will have to wait until post counter resets, and ask again.